# Angular JS -which grid to use

Tags: angularjs

Which is the best control that can be used in Angularjs to list items in a table format . I have seen multiple options like ng-table,ui-grid,ag-grid,kendo-grid.I need features like,sorting,filtering,row styling,header column splitting,scrolls,pagination and also it should be responsive too.

Comment: use ui-grid if you are not worried about IE8

Comment: So pick the one that best suits your needs. You won't get recommendation feedback on this site - it's off topic

Comment: If you intend to load a huge number of rows (enough for the scope soup of angular become a problem) you should check ag-grid. This one has internal implementation independant from angular to keep high performance for lot of contents with filtering, sorting, grouping, etc... maybe less on the responsive design, depend what you really expect for "responsive", a grid with 10 column will always be a problem on a mobile.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference goes out to `ui-grid`, it's very flexible and it allows you to create custom directives/hooks to extend the already rich functionalities. I've used it in a big project with huge datasets and although it required some custom tweaking it was lightning fast.

Answer (score 0):

`Kendo-grid` is the most popular. It provides angular directives for all the controls including `grid`. It also gives all the features you need like sorting, filtering,row styling,header column splitting,scrolls,pagination, exporting data as csv, and much more out of the box.
I have been using it since a long time and kendo-grid is the best.